# PHP's pack/unpack in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've run a cross the following problem:
First i convert a string to an unsigned char array in PHP with:

```
$packed = pack("C*","test123");
echo json_encode($packed);
```

After this i let javascript try to revert the following to a string:

```
//inside of an ajax request
var data = JSON.parse(result);
var string = ""
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
{
   string = string + String.fromCharCode(data[x])
}
```

This works fine for most of the cases, now i know unsigned chars are not unicode (atleast i think so im not sure).

## **The problem:**

But im doing something more advanced with an encryption system.
Comes down to the following problem: converting regular text like this works fine.
But im using the following char (number) on the server/PHP side: 140. (pack("C*",140) gives �)

In unicode this displays as a questionmark icon.
But when you use the fromCharCode function you dont get the same outcome. (String.fromCharCode(140) gives "\u008c" (unicode character))
What am i doing wrong here?
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `"\u008c"` is 140 decimal.

Comment: JSON *should* be UTF-8 encoded. it doesn't sound like `pack` is a good idea.

Comment: @Pointy ah okay, but is there a way to get the same character from the unsigned char code 140. like the same PHP gives? or are they already the same?

Comment: @DanielA.White it comes down to that i dont just transfer a string this is a very simple example. The json transfer works propperly. You receive the correct data only now i have to put the bytes back to their origonal character

Comment: Consider using base64 encoding

Comment: You're passing 140 to `String.fromCharCode()`, and what you get back is `"\u008c"`. What else can JavaScript do? That's how a string with a single character whose numeric character code is 140 would be represented in JavaScript JavaScript strings are always lists of UTF-16 codes, and 140 is the Unicode "PARTIAL LINE BACKWARD" code.